# Failed to install CUDA

Tags: nvidia, cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install CUDA9.2 on WSL and it's stuck at 'Loading new nvidia-396-396.37 DKMS files...'. 
The last few lines of the log are:

```
Setting up nvidia-396 (396.37-0ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) 
A modprobe blacklist file has been created at /etc/modprobe.d to prevent 
Nouveau from loading. This can be reverted by deleting 
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf.
A new initrd image has also been created. To revert, please replace /boot/initrd-4.4.0-17134-Microsoft with /boot/initrd-$(uname -r)-backup.


*****************************************************************************
*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can***
*** be loaded.                                                         ***  
*****************************************************************************

Loading new nvidia-396-396.37 DKMS files.. .
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to install NVIDIA drivers into WSL since there are no Linux Kernel Headers that need to be there for installation of such drivers.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2363

Comment: @Terrance I see. How can I safely remove all NVIDIA and CUDA related packages? Since I used 'dpkg -i some-cuda-deb', I think I need to clean the dependencies, right?

Comment: It should just be the reverse of what you tried but with `remove` instead of `install`.